# Wrong image is set in my tableview cell sometimes when I scroll on my tableview. How can I fix this?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The wrong image is set in my tableview cell sometimes when I scroll on my tableview. How can I fix this? Below is the relevant code in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul), ^{
        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.myURL]]];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.myImageView = image;
        });
    });
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: how you are getting self.myURL ?

Comment: Have you tried at least put a default placeholder image? Just wondering if it's your cells being dequeued.

Comment: Please show your full `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but as @Happiehappie says, you should set the image view to nil or some place holder image before you start downloading otherwise when a cell is reused you will have the old image until the download is complete.

Comment: You need to define custom cell, define imageView and other properties if you are not using placeholder for setting image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First check your cell is nill or not and then set image. Becouse cell is reused on scroll time.**

*see below code it will help you.*

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil)
   {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul), ^{
        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.myURL]]];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.myImageView = image;
        });
    });
}
return cell;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your image data is being downloaded asynchronously but not cancelled upon reuse.

Because UITableViewCells are reused, these types of async calls need to be cancelled upon the cell's reuse, otherwise they can complete when you've already loaded new data into them.

My recommendation is to use a library like SDWebImage to load your images. It downloads, caches and displays your images with less code than what is listed above.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 1):

I did some changes on your code and i think it will help you

```
cell.myImageView = nil; // or  cell.myImageView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:self.myURL]];
NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if (data) {
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    if (image) {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            MyCell *myCell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                            if (myCell)
                                myCell.myImageView = image;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }];
   [task resume];
   return cell;
```

and make  cell.myImageView = nil; or set the placeholder image in

```
- tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

or

simply you can use **SDWebImage** for this 
[tutorial link](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ios-lazy-loading-images)

Answer (score 0):

try this code. You need to set the image to nil when error is occurred or image is not formed with data got in url

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest.init(URL: NSURL.init(string: "self.myURL")!)

        let dataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){(data, response, error) in

            if let imageData = data
            {
                let image = UIImage.init(data: data!)
                if((image) != nil)
                {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                        cell.myImageView = image

                        });
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.myImageView = nil;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                cell.myImageView = nil
                print(error?.description)
            }
        }


        dataTask.resume();
```

*