# The image in tableview cell change when i scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a problem with one of my custom table view cells, the image keeps changing when I scroll and sometimes it sets the wrong image to the cell!.

My code:

```
 let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    cell.img.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
            (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if(error != nil){
            print(error)
        }

        if let imageData = data as NSData? , let image = UIImage(data: imageData) where imageData.length != 0 {
            cell.img.image = image
            cell.img.contentMode = contentMode
            return;
        }

        let cachedResponse = NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().cachedResponseForRequest(request)
        if let cachedResponse = cachedResponse , let image = UIImage(data: (cachedResponse.data)){
            cell.img.image = image;
            cell.img.contentMode = contentMode
        }

    }
```

*Note:

I searched on StackOverflow and I found questions and answers but didn't work for me. One of the Questions:

[Wrong image is set in my tableview cell sometimes when I scroll on my tableview. How can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365215/wrong-image-is-set-in-my-tableview-cell-sometimes-when-i-scroll-on-my-tableview)*

Comment: Check [this repository](https://github.com/pkc456/AbstractDownloading) for faster and smooth scrolling while downloading the images in tableview.

Comment: it changes coz it's reusing.... You need to apply logic to make it same .. and it will be your own..

Comment: Use `SDWebImage` lib to download image instead of `NSURLConnection`, because this lib is used to handle this `async` task .

Comment: `reload` your `tableview` after getting the data and use `placeholder` image.

Comment: thank u @NDoc it work !!

Answer (score 1):

In your custom `UITableviewcell` you need implement `prepareForReuse` method and set image to nil value

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    img.image = nil   
}
```